# Books on electrodynamics of continuous media

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations

There is a classical textbook "Electrodynamics of continuous media" by Landau-Lifschitz.
To my taste, this book does not give enough details on general material, but rather focuses on concrete applications.

**Could you please recommend other books on the same topic.**

Comment: There is an extensive list of book recommendations here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/

Comment: Volume 2 on Classical Field Theory gives the general material, then vol. 8 is taking those results and averaging them then applying them, along with using results from places like thermodynamics from vol. 5 etc..